# Micronaut Spock Functional Test of the controller is throwing a 404 error

Tags: micronaut

I'm getting a 404 error while trying to get a simple greetings controller using spock.

I've tried to modify RxHttpClient to RxStreamingHttpClient

```
My Greetings Controller endpoint:    
@Get("/greetings/{name}")
    String greetings(String name){
        return "hello "+name;
    }
```

Spock Test:

```
class TacRulesControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    EmbeddedServer embeddedServer = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer)

    @Shared
    @AutoCleanup
    RxStreamingHttpClient client = embeddedServer.applicationContext.createBean(RxStreamingHttpClient, embeddedServer.getURL())



    def "greetings controller check" () {

        when:
        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.GET("/greetings/bon")
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.toBlocking().exchange(httpRequest)
        then:
        httpResponse.status == HttpStatus.OK
    }

}
```

1. I expect this test to pass, but getting a 404 error,
2. If the API (in this case `/greetings/bon`) throws an error, why is it not getting propagated and printed in the logs? I've seen cases where the actual API is throwing 400 error, but the declarative httpclient provided by micronaut is throwing a 404 error.

```
    22:27:42.889 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: GET /greetings/bon
    22:27:42.889 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: localhost(19174)
    22:27:42.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-TraceId: 4b31b84f1f36b856
    22:27:42.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-SpanId: 4b31b84f1f36b856
    22:27:42.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - X-B3-Sampled: 0
    22:27:42.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:19174
    22:27:42.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received for Request: GET http://localhost:19174/greetings/bon
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 404 Not Found
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Date: Sat, 29 Jun 2019 03:27:42 GMT
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/json
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 90
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Response Body
    22:27:43.009 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----
    22:27:43.010 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - {"_links":{"self":{"href":"/greetings/bon","templated":false}},"message":"Page Not Found"}
    22:27:43.010 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - ----

    io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Page Not Found

        at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1783)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.DefaultHttpClient$10.channelRead0(DefaultHttpClient.java:1723)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
        at i
```

Comment: Do you have annotation processors enabled in the IDE?  If not, see the notes at https://docs.micronaut.io/1.1.3/guide/index.html#ideSetup.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I was able to resolve this by running from Terminal ( still not working from IntelliJ).

```
void "Greetings check"() {
    given:
    String response = client.toBlocking().retrieve("/greetings/bon")

    expect:
    response.contains("bon")
}
```

looks like this needed for groovy 2.5 and above.

./gradlew test is working, how ever Test execution from intelliJ is not working.